# Fix link on-the-fly as an Error handle for error 3044 or more

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a massive set of linked databases that have the potential to move.  Luckily they are all in ONE working directory of nested folders.

I have effectively created a module that has the path of this working folder defined.
As strWorkingFolder

Now the VBA of the main control center  remains intact for multiple calls running and executing queries (append, delete, insert) etc.  EXCEPT each of the databases that are still linked to the old folder.

I figured that whenever the error 3044 (Not sure of the exact verbiage  "The path to this table does not exist), I could just relink to the correct path - because it is known: It would be strWorkingFolder (concatenated to whatever nested folder the database is in)

I thought I could get away with just linked tables, but apparently, I will need to re-link all kinds of files: csv, Excel, as well as ACCDB.

How can I get it to work?

This is currently what I have setup

```
Sub RemoveLinks()
    Dim tdf As TableDef
    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" And (tdf.Attributes And dbAttachedTable) = dbAttachedTable Then
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete tdf.Name
End If
    Next tdf
    Set tdf = Nothing
End Sub

Sub LinkDatabase(StrDBPath As String)
    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim tdf As TableDef
    Set dbs = OpenDatabase(StrDBPath)
    For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
    If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then
        DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", Trim(StrDBPath), acTable, tdf.Name,    tdf.Name
        SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, "Processing table [" & tdf.Name & "]..."
    End If
Next tdf
    SysCmd acSysCmdClearStatus
    Set dbs = Nothing
    Set tdf = Nothing
End Sub


Sub RefreshLinks(StrDBPath As String)
    Dim tdf As TableDef
    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If (tdf.Attributes And dbAttachedTable) = dbAttachedTable Then
        tdf.Connect = "; Database = " & StrDBPath
        SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, "Processing table [" & tdf.Name & "]..."
        tdf.RefreshLink
    End If
    Next tdf
    Set tdf = Nothing
    SysCmd acSysCmdClearStatus
End Sub
```

And finally, in the error_handler, I will trap 3044 and call

```
Public Sub Relink(strEnginePath)
   Dim dbs As Database
   Set dbs = CurrentDb

   RemoveLinks
   LinkDatabase (strEnginePath)
   RefreshLinks (strEnginePath)


End Sub
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Firstly data in csv's etc isnt going to be particularly useful as it can't be readily updated with queries. Might be an idea to create a backend for this stuff, and a simple form to enable them to be re-imported from the csv's etc when these change - then all you have to do is to manage the links as you're already doing.

Comment: inclusion of CSV's is a request from the client so that no pre-processing is done on their part. They simply schedule a report that kicks out a CSV (only available output) to a directory every morning.  The working folder is a local copy of the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have altered your code so it will handle text and Excel in addition to Access tables. If you have other types attached, you need to modify the code.

**NOTE: With this code, you should NOT delete the links because that will remove all of the attributes you need!**

Also, if you have any parameters following the path/file names in the connect strings, you need to add code to retain that information. I hope you have some standards in place that would allow some logical actions to be taken.

```
Sub RefreshLinks(StrDBPath As String)
Dim iLen    As Integer
Dim iStart  As Integer
Dim iEnd    As Integer
Dim iPos    As Integer
Dim strOldConn As String
Dim strNewConn As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim tdf     As TableDef

On Error GoTo Error_Trap

For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If (tdf.Attributes And dbAttachedTable) = dbAttachedTable Then
        Debug.Print "Table Name: " & tdf.Name
        strOldConn = tdf.Connect                           ' Save the connect string
        iLen = Len(strOldConn)
        iStart = InStr(1, strOldConn, "DATABASE=")         ' Find start of path
        iEnd = InStr(iStart + 1, strOldConn, ";")          ' Is there more after path?
        Debug.Print tdf.Name & ": " & tdf.Connect
        If LCase(left(strOldConn, 4)) = "text" Then        ' Text file attached
            strNewConn = left(strOldConn, iStart + 8) & StrDBPath
        ElseIf LCase(left(strOldConn, 5)) = "excel" Then   ' Excel file attached
            strFile = ""
            For iPos = iLen To 1 Step -1                ' Get the file name from the path
                If Mid(strOldConn, iPos, 1) = "\" Then Exit For
                strFile = Mid(strOldConn, iPos, 1) & strFile
            Next
            If iPos = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Did not find path delimiter '\'" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "for TDF '" & tdf.Name & "'", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Path Delimiter Unknown"
            End If
            strNewConn = left(strOldConn, iStart + 8) & StrDBPath & "\" & strFile
        Else
            ' Assume it is Access table.  If other types, add code to handle.
            strFile = ""
            For iPos = iLen To 1 Step -1                ' Get the file name from the path
                If Mid(strOldConn, iPos, 1) = "\" Then Exit For
                strFile = Mid(strOldConn, iPos, 1) & strFile
            Next
            If iPos = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Did not find path delimiter '\' in connect string '" & strOldConn & "'", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Wrong delimiter?"
            End If
            strNewConn = left(strOldConn, iStart + 8) & StrDBPath & "\" & strFile
        End If
        Debug.Print "      (new): " & strNewConn
        tdf.Connect = strNewConn
        SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, "Processing table [" & tdf.Name & "]..."
        tdf.RefreshLink
    Else
        ' Ignore this table since it is not linked.

    End If
Next tdf
Set tdf = Nothing
SysCmd acSysCmdClearStatus
Exit Sub
Error_Trap:
MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "While processing table: " & tdf.Name & vbCrLf & _
    "Old: " & strOldConn & vbCrLf & _
    "New: " & strNewConn, vbOKOnly, "Relink Error"
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it just using 'RefreshLinks' (omitting the 'RemoveLinks' and 'LinkDatabase' routines)
but I get a 3044 error on  tdf.RefreshLink



Did you intend for me to leave the 'LinkDatabase' routine in place?

How do I handle the:


DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", Trim(StrDBPath), acTable, tdf.Name, tdf.Name


it causes error:

Run-time error '3011:'  The microsoft Access engine could not find the object 'text_reference'.  Make sure the object exists and ...."

Comment: No. only use 'RefreshLinks'.  Either put a breakpoint on the line giving the error, or enable the two 'Debug.Print' that show the table name & the connect string before and after the change. The 3044 is a path/file error. Is it correct? Do you have permissions? Post the before/after display for the failing table.

Comment: I see what the problem is - The text file is linked to a different directory than the database.  For example the database is in C:\Public\WorkingDirectory\Data\TextFiles\  and the database is in the new Working directory C:\NewParentFolder\WorkingDirectory\ACCDB\.  Didn't take that into account that I need to replace the string up to "WorkingDirectory" for every link.

Comment: This would be easy if you had some type of mapping built into a table, or some pattern of what is allowable.

Comment: Wayne, the links do refresh indeed, but they are not premanent.  They only refresh for the task at hand. For example, if I look to check that a particular 'append' query did it's job I can see that it did, but when I look to check the linked table, the OLD link is still there! Is it possible to make them stay connected to the refreshed link?

Comment: I don't know anything about where or when you execute the relink code, and what else you may be doing with code. To troubleshoot, I suggest you open the database, manually run the 'RefreshLinks' code, close the database. Then reopen and check the links. If links are OK, then you have some code or process that is messing up your links.

Comment: Your routine is working perfectly - The problem is in my usage, I forgot to specify the external instances of the database, so every time I got the 3044 error, your code would simply relink the local links.  I changed my code to specify the database for all the external ones.  In some instances, I've gotten a 3343 error 'Unrecognized database format' - even though there is nothing wrong with the database.  All I can assume is that the network doesn't automatically allow databases with VBA code.  But it took it out on those and still get the error. (?)

Comment: Network doesn't care about files with VBA code. Is the 3343 happening every time? If so, is it always the same target database? If so, try C&R on both this and the target database. I will update the code to add error traps that may be helpful.

Comment: Really strange, I changed the routine I was concerned about to ADO and it stopped the error.  Everything else is fine.